# "女の子の名前で雪花って変ですか？" "de" and "tte" usage

Tags: particles, particle-で, particle-って

> 女の子の名前**で**雪花{ゆきか}**って**変ですか？

I came across this question title on a Japanese site while doing some digging about mixing kun and on readings for names, and I understand the overall meaning but I'm confused on the use of "de" and "tte". Help would be much appreciated!
(To clarify, I'm not asking the question)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66181/5010

Answer (score 1):

> 女の子の名前**で**雪花**って**変ですか？

The で means 'in' or 'among'. I guess it's an abbreviation of の中で, but I'm not sure what difference that would make (not a native speaker).

The って is a topic marker. This is equivalent to は but more casual/informal.

The whole translation:

> Among girls names, is Yukika weird?

Comment: The unnaturalness in English of "Among girls' names" clues us that your translation of で is not right. で here means "as" or here "for", as in としては (to shite wa) not "among". "Is Yukika a strange name **for** a girl?" 女の子の名前としては雪花って変ですか。

Comment: @Ben The unnaturalness of my English translation shouldn't give any clue to the Japanese meaning; it's a different language. 'For' may make a better English translation but I'm not convinced this is the grammatical function of で here. Happy to be convinced otherwise though.

Comment: One of the ways I always think of で is "within the context/confines of" (this is also how I often distingush で from に when referring to physical location), so I think perhaps another way to interpret/translate this would be "Is Yukika, in the context of girls' names, weird?"