# What does で mean here in this sentence?

Tags: particles, sentence

> みんな同じ地域で小学校から育ってきたところに学年で僕1人だけ渋谷から引っ越して入学したんだよね。

The で here confuses me, here is what I think the translation is and I'm not sure if mine is even correct.

> When everyone from the same region grew up from elementary school, (Then the 2nd で confuses me)

I think the 2nd で serves as the location particle

> When everyone from the same region grew up from elementary school, in the school year I was the only one who moved from Shibuya to transfer to a school.

I'm pretty much confused on how the particles are used.

Comment: Did you understand the "school year" as a location?

Comment: I don't know what else both of the で serves for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

学年で means 同学年で(in the same grade), so it means "I was the only one who moved from Shibuya in the same grade".

Comment: Might be a silly question but, で can be used even if the place isn't physical?

Comment: で is not only used in "the place" like the English word "in".I think this "で" is similar to "among",

Comment: @339jff See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66190/5010).